# How to send data from one activity to another by using getIntent() instead of usinf new Intent();

Tags: android

usually we send data from one activity to another by using:-

```
Intent i=new Intent("<action name>");
i.putExtras("name",data);
startActivity(i);
```

My question is can we send data from one activity to another by using:-

```
Intent i=this.getIntent();
i.putExtras("name",data);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
finish();
```

If yes please explain the concept.
Also,these two classes are in the different projects in Eclipse.My another question is, is it possible to send data through intent to another activity situated in another project??

Comment: As far as I know, `getIntent` is the current intent. And when creating a new Intent, you specify where the data should be sent

Comment: If you are starting that `Activity` with `startActivityForResult()` then that would be the correct way. Then you will receive the data in `onActivityResult()` of the receiving/initial Activity.

Comment: I am trying to send data from the above written to another activity's onActivityResult() method

Comment: Then use the first method. What's the problem?

Comment: the above written method is in the another project which is a "is library" project and i will be using it in more than one places but if i use first one i will have to mention either class name or action name which will make the "is library" project specific to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're starting from Activity A and going to Activity B using startActivityForResult()

Now we're in Activity B and want to go back to Activity A:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) i.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras()); 
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

Doing something like that will allow you to pass back the extras from the calling Intent (if they exist), which would then be reachable from Activity A's onActivityResult() method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do so, when you call another intent for a result. ie startActivityForResult(Intent,Request_Code);